# Redirection to the previous query page after authentication in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

When a user requests a protected route, I'd like to redirect them to the login page. After successful authentication, I want to redirect the user back to the originally requested protected route.

On next 12 it I used to do it like this

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

const router = useRouter();

const onSuccess = () => {
    const prev = router.query.from as string;
    router.replace(prev|| '/');
};
```

Comment: This `from` is a query string (url parmater)?

Comment: Yeah it can be, but not always

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you're using `next-auth`, but It's the same in any way.

It's the same concept, when you redirect them to the login page just add a searchParam to the url

```js
if (!session) {
  redirect("/login?from=" + pathname)
}
```

Then on the login page, set the callbackUrl of `signIn()` options to this path or URL.

```js
import {useSearchParams} from "next/navigation"
import {signIn} from "next-auth/react"

const searchParams = useSearchParams()
const from = searchParams.get("from")

await signIn("google", {
  callbackUrl: from ?? "/"
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve by using

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: I was facing a run-time error when doing that. next 13 suggests to use next/navigation instead of next/router